# Regression vs time series for UK house prices and consumption

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, econometrics, nonlinear-regression

i have to do a report on uk house prices and their effect on consumption, looking at research clearly a time series and regression is the best method. Please can someone answer me what they both achieve and if using both may be better for facialitating my research not just one? also what figures will i have to input to show the correlation of this will i have to use a multiple regression, how many sets of data will be needed etc

Comment: maybe this will help:http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/machine-learning-features-engineering-from-date-time-data?rq=1#